# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct():

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, oracle11g, xampp

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (15/JAN/20) at position 0 (1):`

...on line 26

```
$first_installment_date = new datetime($aData[0]->FIRST_INSTALL_DATE);
```

php codeigniter was working fine before ...when i reinstall oracle n xampp..it shows error

Answer (score 4):

`15/JAN/20)` is not a [valid format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) for `DateTime()`. You will need to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse that date:

```
//Assuming YY/Mon/DD
$first_installment_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y/M/d', $aData[0]->FIRST_INSTALL_DATE);
```

Comment: thanks!! but how come that error occur before it was working fine but when i uninstall n reinstall xampp and oracle 11g xe  it shows error!!! its is still working on my  other PC same programs installed...

Comment: Really, I can't think of any reason off of the top of my head other then possibly different PHP versions supporting different date formats and one of the versions of PHP you installed is different then the others.

Comment: TQ ANYWAYS KEEP HELPING :p

Answer (score -1):

```
public __construct ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )
```

Are you sure the "**$aData[0]->FIRST_INSTALL_DATE**" isn't null?

[PHP DateTime Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)